# rsa, ssh and repository

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, security

I'm using kubuntu and I generated a key using this command:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and I prompted the passphrase and the location here:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/b/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/b/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/b/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

I send to the host the public key file and when I try to clone the git repository it ask me a password (of himself, that I don't have).
From the other side they say that everything is ok.

I have three files in the `/.ssh`: known_hosts, mykey.txt (private key) and mykey.txt.pub (public key).

What do I have to do for cloning the repository without that it ask me the password?

**Edit**

I don't know about the server side. I guess they have ssh and they used that command because they did it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your ssh-keygen output there, the key was saved to id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, which is where they normally go.  If you renamed them to mykey.txt and mykey.txt.pub then you need to rename them back.

Comment: Yes, I've solved right now regenerating the keys with that name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say where you put the public key file on the remote host. Ssh comes with convenience script `ssh-copy-id` (although this sends *all* your public keys, which may not be what you want).

What is the actual file name of your private key ? id_rsa ? Else `ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey.txt` might be useful at each login.

You did not say if git was indeed using ssh at all.

All these can be clarified with actual logs of your attempts.